# Azure DevOps self-hosted agent in Container instance - network rules

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-container-instances

I am running Azure DevOps Ubuntu self-hosted agent as container in the Container Instances. What are the minimum inbound and outbound network traffic rules so the agent can operate? I tried ports 80 and 443 TCP for both in and outbound but the container is still not able to find the DevOps Agent pool (it says `[1;36m1. Determining matching Azure Pipelines agent...[0m`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As depicted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#communication-with-tfs), only outbound HTTP(S) on port 443 is required.